# Distributed storage with UNC share?

Tags: linux, filesystems, dfs, distributed-filesystems, storage

What approach would you take to build a massive storage, using multiple PC's running Linux OS?

The recipe I would like to use sounds like this: take 10 PCs equipped with six 2TB disks, install your favorite flavor of *NIX OS on each PC, configure some sort of DFS software and finally share the created storage (as UNC) with your friends and colleagues.

There seems to be quite a few solutions providing most of the features one would want, except UNC sharing.

Any suggestions?

Miha

Answer (score 1):

By UNC sharing do you mean CIFS?

The solution that comes to mind is [AFS, Andrew File System](http://www.openafs.org/).  It works in a mixed environment.  Most of the cluster solutions like gluster or lustre are Linux only and require a server setup to share the data via CIFS using [SAMBA](http://www.samba.org/).

Comment: I should also mention that Samba does support Microsoft's DFS.